# How to add special character when concatenating 3 textbox values by using keyup?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have 3 Text boxes for Address1, Address2, Town.

I have to display these values in a single line by using a comma like Address1,Address2,Town by using the keyup function in jquery.

Here is my code. here how can I add "," when type address2 and Town?

```
$("#address1").keyup(function(){
   var val = $("#address1").val()+$("#address2").val()+$("#Town").val();
   $("#addr").html(val);
});
$("#address2").keyup(function(){
   var val = $("#address1").val()+$("#address2").val()+$("#Town").val();
   $("#addr").html(val);
});
$("#Town").keyup(function(){
   var val = $("#address1").val()+$("#address2").val()+$("#Town").val();
   $("#addr").html(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method and [**.join()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the returned array elements, by default `.join()` uses `,` as glue.

```
var $elems = $("#address1, #address2, #Town").keyup(function() {
   // Create an array and join it's elements
   var val = $elems.map(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value) || null;
   }).get().join();

   $("#addr").html(val);
});
```

Comment: If I might make a suggestion, change the line to `return $.trim(this.value) || null;` and you won't get the extra commas. The `.map()` function won't add an entry to the array if `null` is returned. BTW, this is nice answer.